# Add error logging to createApi if fetching fails (Redux Toolkit with Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux-toolkit

We have various fetches using [createApi](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi) with Redux Toolkit. These are often done with Server Side Rendering (SSR) in nextjs [following the SSR/Next.js/Redux Toolkit docs here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/server-side-rendering#server-side-rendering-with-nextjs). Sometimes the backend URL (`baseQuery`) is just down, and the API won't work at all. All we get is a blank page in next.js. Network tab of browser DevTools shows no error, because it is SSR. Next.js logs nothing.

I would like to do a `console.log` or `console.warn` if any of the hooks to the [endpoints](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#endpoints) of `createApi` fail. However, the [error handling docs of Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling) only describe how to handle the error on the React JSX page using the `error` prop. However, I would just like to do a console.log on the next.js server whenever there is a problem with the SSR fetches.

At the moment, the SSR fetches just fail silently. Next.js only prints logs if one does a deliberate console.log, see https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production#logging

How can I add some logging to `createApi` so that whenever the API fails then there is some kind of logging?